# is there a way to return the value to twig as in angular js using $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, twig

```
function addCourse(x){
    $.post("../section/pages/tableContent.php", {data: x}, function(result) {
        //here
    });
};
```

in angular i can do it like so

```
$http.post("../section/pages/tableContent.php", {data: x}).success(function (result) {
    $scope.students=result.records;
});
```

as i want to loop the resulting array/object

Comment: Twig is processed in the server, so you cannot use any twig functions but you can use jquery functions like .html() to set any value you need

Answer (score -1):

Question is not very clear. But looks like you want to use code similar to angularjs in php+twig.

Since you are using ajax, everything has to be done on client-side, but twig is server-side, so it won't help. But you can use jquery itself.

```
function addCourse(x){
      $.post("../section/pages/tableContent.php", {data: x},                   
           function(result){
                $.each( result, function( i, val ) {
                     $("#id_of_your_ul").append("<li>"+val+"</li>");
                });
      });
};
```

If you put in more information about what exactly you are trying. I can provide what exactly you have to do.

Comment: This goes against angular you are using jquery.

Comment: If the question is unclear please use the comment system before answering.

Comment: @Mathew Berg there is jQuery lite in Angular by default. He just uses it wrong way.

Comment: Doesn't matter, you should be using the angular wrapped $post